# I didn't find the mysql-connector-java-version.jar file in the folder of J/connector

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I downloaded the j/connector from mysql website. But I could not find the executable JAR file instead there is another zip file. But when I extracted that another zip file inside I could find JAR file .[Instead of being jar file there is zip file with no jar file inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTACP.png)
If u have then also u can please share me the file.

Comment: You can find the jar in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java, although i recommend to use maven project. The depedency is    <!-- Conector/libreria de MYSQL para java -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: I just downloaded the ZIP file from "https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/" (platform independent). It contains several file like "build.xml", "CHANGES" and others. And it contains the "mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar". Somehow your computer supresses the ".jar" extension and shows the jar file as "WinRAR archive"...

Answer (score 0):

You can open this link and search the version that you need https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java, although i recommend to use maven project.

The pom is

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- send email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Configuracion del ORM de spring boot para persistencia -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Conector/libreria de MYSQL para java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you are using spring, you only need the next in the properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://:@/?reconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

Comment: It is not helping me I am completely new here. I watched every tutorial in youtube. There is JAR file in every video but   zip file in mine. If u have exectutable JAR file please share the download link.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the first zip file but don't extract the other zip file. Instead copy that zip file and paste it in separate folder inside your project folder. For example, if you have a project folder called `JDBC`(open the `JDBC` folder in eclipse), then create a sub folder as `lib` and then open the `lib` folder in your local machine and paste that `mysql-connector-j` zip file in it. Now, eclipse will properly detect it as jar file. Now right click the jar file and add to the build path.